# In ios tableview, why section is a NSIndexSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexset

I am newbie to iOS development so this question is quite silly, but I do have a hard time figuring out how the following code works:

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type{  

  if (type==NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
       [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   }
}
```

why does `NSIndexSet` represents section here? also, in this example `sectionIndex` is just a number, does it make a `NSIndexSet` a set with only one number? If it only has one number, why not just use a `int` to represent it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First, what NSIndexSet is. NSIndexSet is an extremely efficient way of expressing a collection of unique integers where many of the integers are likely to be successive.

Let's say you want to express `[1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15]`. That can be expressed a lot more tightly as `[{1,5},{10,6}]`, where that notation is meant to convey two *ranges*, i.e. what you'd get if you put together `NSMakeRange(1,5)` and `NSMakeRange(10,6)`.

They could have asked for an array of NSNumber, but doing it as an NSIndexSet guarantees uniqueness of every entry (it's a *set*) and permits great efficiency of storage and calculation.

(They could *not* have asked for an array of Int, because you can't put an Int into an NSArray; it has to be an object. Again, this adds to the efficiency of NSIndexSet - there is no need to unwrap all those NSNumbers! An array of NSNumber would be a very inefficient way to communicate this information.)

Now for your particular question: it *doesn't* have to be only one number! Note the name: `deleteSections:`. See the "s" on the end? You are allowed to delete multiple sections in one command. The fact that in this case you *happen* to be deleting only one section is beside the point. And no efficiency is lost thereby.

Answer (score 0):

An NSIndexSet is an immutable collection of unique unsigned integers optimized for storing indexes to data structures. The method `deleteSections:` takes an NSIndexSet as its parameter because, well, it allows the programmer to pass a set of indexes for deletion. In this case, you only want to delete one row, so you pass an NSIndexSet with just one member.

Further information: [NSIndexSet documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [deleteSections: method documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/deleteSections:).